# More information about theming in SharePoint 2019 Modern experience

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019

I got help in another thread (thank you!) and started to test theming my SP2019 Modern exp with the Set-PnpTheme. I just want to make some minor changes, like color etc. I've taken a look on this documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-deploy-a-custom-theme-in-sharepoint

It refers to http://{SiteCollectionName}/_catalogs/theme/15/ - the problem is, you dont really know which theme is which, due to the naming.

I've also tried out the Sharepoint Color Palette Tool. But it's really hard to "convert" and theming a classic theme, and convert the different elements to a modern theme, so to speak.

Is there maybe a tool like the Palette tool for modern exp? Or any tool at all to help me upload a custom MODERN EXP theme using the Set-PnpTheme command?

Why is it so complicated to apply a theme to SharePoint 2019 modern experience?

Answer (score -1):

I got a tip for this app, and I think this will solve my problem. :)

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/js-theme-manager-2019

Comment: Interesting someone DOWNVOTED my answer. Just FYI, yes, this SOLVED my problem perfectly. The app worked like a charm, and I can finally use the same color theme in my SP2019 as in SPO.